# Bad encoding - PhpMyAdmin/MySql

Tags: python, mysql, encoding, utf-8, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to add rows into the table using `mysql.connector` module. These rows are read from a txt file. The problem is that for example 'č' or 'ľ'sign is visible as '?' in `PhpMyAdmin`. I've tried to set the database encoding to `utf-8 bin`, using `operations` button in `PhpMyAdmin`. The file is according to `notepad++` in `utf-8` encoding. What should I do to solve it?

Here a piece of the code where inserting into database:

```
with open('file') as f:
    for line in f:
        splitted = line.split('*')
        splitted = ["\'{0}\'".format(element) for element in splitted]
        insert = ', '.join(splitted)

        try:

            cursor.execute("""
              INSERT INTO table_data VALUES(DEFAULT,%s)
            """%(insert))

            cnx.commit()
        except:
            print 'ERROR'
cnx.close()
```

[image]

WAMP - MySQL console - SELECT * FROM table piece:
[image]

Comment: What does the data look like when you query it in mysql (command line)?

Comment: I tried it and it is the same, I've uploaded the picture of SELECT * FROM table up there. What should I do? Thanks

Comment: Check the character set of the MySQL database to see if it can store the ? in "Ra?ianska". The simplest way to do this is by again using the mysql CLI and execute a direct insert "INSERT INTO yourtable(col) VALUES ("Ra?ianska"); " (Replace ? with your real character).

Comment: INSERT INTO table_data(nazov) VALUES ("Račianska"); But in PhpMyAdmin I see 'Ra?ianska' again.

Comment: I get it, the problem was that I had database encoding set to utf-8 however column were in latin. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You need utf8 everywhere.  utf8 bytes in your client, tell mysql that your client has utf8 bytes, `CHARACTER SET utf8` on the column,  on web page, etc.

In your screen shots you show some accented characters coming through correctly, some not.  Please provide a list of the working / non-working ones.  (A few of each will suffice.)  What language(s) are you trying to handle?

Since some characters are turning into '?', the number of possible causes is somewhat limited.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for one table in trouble.

Please provide `SELECT col, HEX(col)...` for some cell in trouble.  If it says `3F` in the hex where there should be an accented letter, then the problem is on input, and the data is irrecoverable.

If the problem is on input, I would *guess* that you have non-`latin1` bytes going into a `latin1` column.  Once we 'fix' the input, we can address the output.

To get the 'console' to show utf8 characters:  The command "chcp" controls the "code page". chcp 65001 provides utf8, but it needs a special charset installed, too.  To set the font in the console window: Right-click on the title of the window → Properties → Font → pick Lucida Console

[My charset blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll) discusses these issues and more.